# Can I use jtracert to sequence diagram a unit test running in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, junit, sequence-diagram, jtracert

How would I go about using jtracert to sequence diagram a junit test being run within eclipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the "Run" dialog, select your JUnit configuration and go the "Arguments" tab.
Add jTracert parameters to "VM arguments" section (something like -javaagent:/home/dmitrybedrin/work/jtracert/deploy/jTracert.jar)

Click on "Run" button.

You will see the following in the "Console" tab:

jTracert agent started
Waiting for a connection from jTracert GUI on port 7007

Now execute jTracert gui and connect to the jTracert agent.

That's it - you will see the sequence diagrams now!

Comment: You so deserve a medal for this answer. I was extremely frustrated trying to get this to work... Shoot me. So happy now that it does. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There's a small mistake in my previous answer - you should specify -javaagent:/home/dmitrybedrin/work/jtracert/deploy/jTracert.jar=**7007** to "VM arguments" section.